# ERROR: Unrecognized TLD for nameserver ns1.111.222.333.444

Tags: domain, vps, nameserver

I have a virtual private server(VPS) with some IP address like `http://111.222.333.444/`, and wanted to publish my Angular-NodeJS project on it, so I bought a domain with default nameservers like `ns1.example.com , ns2.example.com`. Then I tried to change the default nameservers to the followings:

```
ns1.111.222.333.444
ns2.111.222.333.444
```

But I get this error message:

```
ERROR: Unrecognized TLD for nameserver ns1.111.222.333.444
```

What is the problem and how can I connect my VPS to the domain I have bought?

Comment: `111.222.333.444` is neither an IPv4 address nor an hostname. It is just garbage. If you used real names, your question would be so much better...

Answer (score 1):

In order to point the domain you have purchased to your VPS you need to create an A record pointing to your VPS's IP. There is no need to modify your nameserver records.

According to the DNS specification, the authoritative nameservers are given by name, not IP. So that is why that error pops up. And unless you have very complex DNS needs, you shouldn't host your own nameserver.

So revert your nameserver records to the way they were originally, then add an A record with your VPS's IP and you'll be set. Keep in mind it might take many hours for these changes to propagate.

Most domain registrars have tutorials on how to add/remove/edit DNS records on their platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You must not change **NS** records, you must add **A** record

```
Name         TTL    Type    Address
you-domain   3600    A      111.222.333.444
```

For any hosting you can find examples of how to do this, for example:
https://support.us.ovhcloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012042099-How-to-Connect-Your-VPS-to-Your-Domain-Name

Comment: `111.222.333.444` is not an IPv4 address, hence the record you show is invalid. Please look at RFC5737 for proper obfuscation.

Comment: `111.222.333.444` was used as an example. I think everyone understands that instead of the `111.222.333.444` you need to put your real IP address

Comment: It can not be an example since it is not a valid IP address. Why not use real IP addresses then? Bad data hurts things, especially if there are proper solutions (see RFC 5737). And it hurts even more when explaining things to someone that may not fully understand everything discussed as it will create unwarranted confusion.

Comment: Thanks, I think my VPS provider is Hetzner but I can't find it's instruction,

Comment: Try searching here https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Kategorie:DNS_Console